# Azure Pipeline webpack script failing using windows-2022

Tags: .net, azure, webpack, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have an Azure Pipeline configured to build and deploy a .NET 5 application to an on prem server. This works fine for .NET 5, but after upgrading to .NET 6, I had to update the `vmImage` from `windows-latest` to `windows-2022`, as `windows-latest` doesn't have the .NET 6 SDKs on (according to https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907). This was the error I received

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.404\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5):
> error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
> 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

That makes sense, so I've updated the `vmImage` to `windows-2022`, and it now gets past that bit, but the pipeline now fails on the webpack task.

**Original YAML file (failed on NuGet task due to not having .NET 6 tools available)**

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'ci'
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/GIFrameworkMaps.Web'
    
- script: webpack --mode=development
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/GIFrameworkMaps.Web'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'giframeworkmaps-$(Build.SourceVersion)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

**Updated YAML file**

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
...Everything else the same as original file above...
```

This now fails on the script command to run webpack

```
Generating script. 
Script contents: webpack --mode=development
========================== Starting Command Output =========================== 
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\501f6f1d-71f5-4286-ac14-dda4b0c8948c.cmd""
'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'. Finishing: CmdLine
```

In vague attempts at fixing the problem I've also tried changing the `Npm` task to just a normal `script` task with `npm install` and `npm-install --save-dev` with no luck. I've also put the `npm install` and `webpack` commands into a single `script` task but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack is not installed by default on the [windows-2022 image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md), while it is installed on [windows-latest](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/02b0bf3e1a42323b0b445599ae08907599e09b46/images/win/toolsets/toolset-2019.json#L414).

However, you can easily install it as part of your build pipeline:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I did have to install `webpack-cli` as well, but it asked quite clearly for that. I would've thought that my attempt using `npm-install --save-dev` would have done a similar thing though, since I have webpack and webpack-cli in my package.json